# How to memoize a function in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, memoization

I have a function `string --> string` in PowerShell that is quite slow to execute, and I would like to *memoize* it, that to preserve all the input/output pairs to speed-up an execution that calls this function over and over. I can think of many complicated ways of achieving this. Would anyone have anything not too convoluted to propose?

Comment: @Paul Yes, it's a [programming term](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization).

Comment: learned something new again :) thanks

Comment: The easiest manner I can think of is to use a global scope hash table and check it every time.  Do you need to store the memoization between executions?  You might want to store the results in a CSV that you load every time, or in an SQLite database.

Comment: You also might consider just writing the function as a console app or a .NET library and loading the assembly.  It depends on how much performance you're talking about, I guess.

Comment: @BaconBits rather than a .NET library, I would suggest a .NET PowerShell module (unless you wanted to use it from PowerShell and a .NET application)

Comment: @Swoogan Well, the point would be to mitigate the performance issue by using a binary instead of a script.  In other words, memoization may not be the best way to improve performance of the function. Maybe it's a deeply recursive function and using lookup tables will help tremendously, but maybe it's better to just make the code run faster and not have to deal with managing more objects or steps.  And sure, you could build it as a binary PowerShell module, but since you'd still have to code the binary that may not add sufficient value on a single script for the increased dev time.

Comment: @BaconBits I was only referring to the strategy of the binary implementation. Too many developers are unaware of .NET PowerShell modules and how easy there are to make. Any time I see someone make a console exe or a .NET Class Library to use from PowerShell, I die a little inside.

Comment: @Swoogan I see your point, but I find that too often people try to force everything in PowerShell into the .NET frame of mind. A scripting language isn't necessarily about building a robust application. It's about getting things done. My biggest problem with the PowerShell community is that it's too focused on making everything .NET. Scripting for administration should be about getting things done, not getting things done *with .NET* or getting things done The Microsoft Way™. If it's faster to use a console app, I say do that. I die inside when I see someone re-implement `7z.exe` in .NET.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, here's a shot at it. I definitely cannot claim this is a good or efficient method; in fact, even coming up with something that works was tricky and a PowerShell expert might do better.

This is *massive* overkill in a scripting language, by the way (a global variable is far simpler), so this is definitely more of an intellectual exercise.

```posh
function Memoize($func) {
    $cachedResults = @{}
    {
        if (-not $cachedResults.ContainsKey("$args")) {
            echo "Remembering $args..." #for illustration
            $cachedResults.Add("$args", $func.invoke($args))
        }
        $cachedResults["$args"]
    }.getnewclosure()
}


function add($a, $b) {
    return $a + $b;
}

$add = Memoize ${function:add};

&$add 5 4
&$add 5 4
&$add 1 2
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if writing a .NET PowerShell module is practical in your case. If it is, you could use the similar technique as I did with one of my projects.

Steps:

1. Rewrite your function as a cmdlet
2. Have a static class with a static hash table where you store the results
3. Add a -Cache flag to the cmdlet so you can run it with and without the cache (if needed)

My scenario is a little different as I am not using a hash.
My cache: https://github.com/Swoogan/Octopus-Cmdlets/blob/master/Octopus.Extensions/Cache.cs
Usage: https://github.com/Swoogan/Octopus-Cmdlets/blob/master/Octopus.Cmdlets/GetEnvironment.cs

Answer (score 0):

I thought of something pretty simple, like the following:

```
$array = @{}

function memoized
{
    param ([string] $str)

    if ($array[$str] -eq $null)
    {
        $array["$str"]  = "something complicated goes on here"
    }

    return $array[$str]
}

memoized "testing"
```